# Разные размеры кнопок в TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Не могу понять как сделать одинаковые кнопки если в одной из них длинный текст.
Сделал такой Layout и все вроде хорошо пока не вводишь длинный текст в кнопку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тогда выходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_span="4"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/android_icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/android" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/linear_layout" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/android_icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/android" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/relative_layout" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/android_icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/android" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/frame_layout" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/android_icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/android" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/grid_layout" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените у всех кнопок

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

на

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```